# making footer to stick at the bottom of the page when ui:insert is used

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

hi i have a main page like this.

**html view**

```
<html>   

<head>  

</head>  

<body>  

<div class="wrapper">  

<div class="content">  

<ui:include src="/templates/include/header.xhtml"/>  

<div class="left_menu">  

<ui:include src= />  

</div>  

<div class="content_container">  

<ui:insert name="body">Body</ui:insert>  

</div>      

</div>  

<div class="footersathi">  

<ui:insert name="footer">footer</ui:insert>  

</div>  

</div>      

</body>  

</html>
```

**end of html view**

**css**

```
.wrapper {  
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
     }

.content {
margin:0;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.left_menu {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

.content_container {
position: absolute;
top: 176px;
left: -15px;
}

.footersathi {
width:100%;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:blue;
}
```

**end of css**

The problem is since iam using **ui:insert name=body** tag The pages that iam including with name body some pages have less content and some pages have more content but footer is not changing relative to that content instead it is fixing to particular position could any one help me how to resolve this problem when ui:insert is used.

Answer (score 0):

Why do use `position: absolute;` on the footer? If you set `position: static'` (which is the default if you don't specify it), the footer wil be appear at the end of your document automatically..

If this doesn't answer your question, please make your question clearer :)

For what you want, I think you can avoid positioning elements out of the normal flow. Look for example [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm), for an example on how to create a layout using CSS.

Comment: Hi Wesley thanks for your reply.When i changed position:absolute to position:static, footer is coming to top of the page.                HTML code I have written above is a template it will include different pages by using this statement <ui:include src="/templates/include/header.xhtml"/> this statement is common to all the pages, but the statement <ui:insert name="body">Body</ui:insert> is different i will use <ui:define name="body"> statement and i will write content here.

Comment: This is continuation of above comment                                                                    The problem is I have pages with low content and with high content with low content footer is working fine but with high content the footer is sticking in middle of the page not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The reason that the footer appears on top is because other elements are positioned absolute and taken out of the flow. You should avoid positioning as much as possible and let HTML take it's natural flow. In this case, try removing the positioning from the content_container as well. This should put the content on top of your footer for example.

Comment: Thanks Wesley Actually the real problem is with position:absolute only. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to accept one of the answers to close this question :)

Comment: Hi Wesley actually there is another problem,The link you have provided to me is not working fine if i zoom in or zoom out the contents what i have placed in content-left and content main are changing what i need to do if the contents should not change in left and main even if zoomin or zoomout is done.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper div class (with the css you provided for it) prior to the footer is I think a solution proposed when you want the footer always occupies the bottom of the page.

As for your problem, div classes are by default on top of each other unless float or inline-block is specified. So if you remove:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

As explained by Wesley, your layout should be fine.

Comment: if what you want is to make the footer stick in the bottom of the page, please follow this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: Thanks Edwin Actually the real problem is with position:absolute only. Thanks a lot